# Word document is always Read-Only when opened with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, ms-word, xamarin.android, android-internal-storage

I am trying to **open and edit** a **word document** located in my external storage in my Xamarin.Android App with **MS-Word** with this code:

```
File wordFile = new File(wordFilePath);
wordFile.SetWritable(true);

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(wordFilePath);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;

Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Context, Context.PackageName + ".provider", wordFile);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);

intent.SetData(uri);

Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

The problem is, that the file is always **Read-Only**. When I open the document via **any file explorer** (e.g. File Manager Pro) , it is **not Read-Only** and I can edit the file.

Am I missing any permission that i need to set in my app or FileProvider?

**EDIT:**

- I am **logged in** with my **Office Account** in the Android Word App
- Using **WPS Office works just fine**, so it has to be a special problem with MS-Word
- using `intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionEdit);` does not make a difference
- using `intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");` does not make a difference
- similar behavior using **Google Docs**: Using a FileExplorer I am able to open and edit the file. If I open the file with Google Docs through my app I can edit the file, but if I click Save, the app asks me to ***"Update the file to the new DOCX-Format"***. Then I can save the file to a new directory.
- The combination of `ActionView` & `SetDataAndType` as it is used in the file explorer does not work either

like this

```
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

---

**Intent Comparision:**

I used an **Intent Intercept App** to compare the intent from my app with the intent from a file explorer:

---

*My App (Word file is Read-Only):*
[image]

---

*File-Explorer (Word file can be edited):*
[image]

- using MIME-type from the file explorer `intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");` does not make a difference

Comment: try to use `Intent.ActionEdit` instead of `Intent.ActionView`

Comment: I already tried that, does not help

Comment: intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/msword"); set type to have a try

Comment: i tried that too

Comment: Just to be clear... you tried replacing `SetData()` with `SetDataAndType()` and set your MIME type to that really long value from the second screenshot? (I'm not a Xamarin user, but I assume that they have a `SetDataAndType()` to match `SetData()`, the way we do in Java/Kotlin). If you have tried this, and it still did not work, you might want to update your question with the revised code and screenshots.

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in the last point below the screenshots

Comment: but i added the new point in the edit section to make it clear :)

Comment: it's launch flags `1000 0000` vs. `1300 0000`, whatever `3` might be.

Comment: You can refer the following for the writing purpose -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667865/10941112

Comment: @K.Dexter Try to launch only with **intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);** Remove all **AddFlags** calls. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Duplicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157389/when-using-android-file-provider-files-dont-have-correct-permissions-despite-f

Comment: @mmmatey your suggestion leads to an error in word: **Can't open file | Try saving the file on the device and then opening it**

Comment: Just wrote a technical documentation what I still found out: https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-android/issues/150#issuecomment-514401775
Microsoft has to fix this problem as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you use `ActionEdit` instead of `ActionView`, and NOT

```
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
```

With this, I am able to open a .doc file that is editable, however, I am not able to save the file to the original location (in my app's sandbox). Word will always suggest saving a copy. After scratching my head for days, I suspect this is by design by Microsoft, not anything wrong in our code, though I can't be sure...